# compile the android perf from the $AOSP/extenal/linux-tools-perf

Tags: android, events, perf

When I downloaded the android source code 4.3 from Google, I found the perf source code already existed in $AOSP/extenal/linux-tools-perf. But after I compiled the project for emulator, I didn't find 'perf' in system/bin. Why?

Should I explicitly point out the make target? Like "make perf_eng" ?
Or I should choose a android device as a target?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have to do "mm" in "extenal/linux-tools-perf"

1. source build/envsetup.sh
2. lunch < >
3. cd extenal/linux-tools-perf
4. mm

Comment: I compiled this module separately, but encountered errors. I think there missed some files in my downloaded project. I downloaded the 4.4 branch and compiled from scratch. Problems seem to be solved.